# Passing parameters to an EXE assembly

Tags: c#

I'd like to launch my application from another utility app and pass a parameter. The simplest solution:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appPath, param);
```

... is not an option as I'd like to prevent other people from providing the parameter to the app. In other words: I'd like to lauch my application with a param *only* from my utility app.

How to achieve that?

Thanks,
Leszek

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible, although you can achieve a degree of security through obscurity.

Comment: So you want to make an executable non-executable to anything other than your app, is that right?

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this?  I can think of a few solutions, but knowing why you are doing this would help.

Comment: What if you launch with two params, one of which is a password?

Comment: Is your utility app .NET or native ?

Comment: Consider using named pipes for inter-process communication.

Comment: sounds like you need to look at Arguments Param try looking up StartInfo.Arguments

Comment: all this is about inter processes communication. I think what Steve suggests is probably the easiest way.

Comment: The main application is a game and the utility is a level designer that can start the game from a specified level. I don't want users to lauch the game from any level.

Answer (score 2):

If you (for security reason) don't want to pass meaningful parameters to start your main program then you can use Anonymous Pipes (starting from Net 4)
Basically you follow this pseudocode

- From the utility, create the anonymous pipe and start your main program passing the handle of the pipe.
- The main program use the handle passed to listen on the anonymous pipe
- The utility program send the message using the anonymous pipe

[Here you can find a detailed example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx)

In this way, there is a parameter passed from the utility to the main program representing the anonymous pipe, but no other program or user can easily fake the main program. If you add to this scenario also some form of secret handshaking between the two programs you will get a robust protection.

Comment: I'm working with .NET 3.5 but Anonymous Pipes sound interesting.

Comment: I don't know your code, but this seems a good argument to upgrade to 4 or 4.5

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting the process to go like this:

1. Start UtilityProgram.exe
2. Do something in UtilityProgram that starts YourApplication.exe

And you want to make sure no one else can start YourApplication.exe outside of the UtilityProgram.

I think the simplest way would be to require a parameter in YourApplication.exe that is complex, sort of like a password.

So, in YourApplication.exe, your code could look like this:

```
static int Main(string[] args){
    if (args.Length != 1) {
        // We got more than 1 parameter, exiting with a code of -1.
        return -1;
    }

    if (args[0] != "abc123def456ghi") {
        // We got 1 parameter, but it wasn't right, exiting with a code of -2.
        return -2;
    }

    // Got 1 matching parameter
    // Code goes here
}
```

And then in UtilityProgram.exe, you can do this:

```
Process MyApp = new Process();
MyApp.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\to\MyApp\exe";
MyApp.StartInfo.Arguments = "abc123def456ghi";
MyApp.Start();
```

Comment: Just launch the [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and see the argument

Comment: @L.B Thank you, this is an excellent point, and totally true. It depends on how secure the OP is wanting to go, and how technically savvy the target audience is.

Comment: I actually *want* users to launch my application outside of the Utility program. I don't want them to provide any params. The password is a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

You can make one of your app's parameters a password that you only know.  Then you can pass that parameter from the launching utiliy.

Comment: Not a bad idea - This is feasible if there's not an inordinate security concern. It would be, of course, childs play to come along with RedGate's Reflector or a similar tool, and decompile the .exe and get the "secret" password, so if there's a security concern this wouldn't be a very good solution.

Comment: this is quite feasible I have done something similar and stored the password in the .config file as Encrypted string and in the code and wrote encryption code to check the pass word passed against the encrypted password..

Comment: Just launch the [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and see the argument

Comment: I'm going to obfuscate the code so it should help a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that came to my mind is to accept the parameter only in the Debug build. I have control over both applications and I'm the only one who needs to lauch the main application with a param. I could strip this functionality off in the release build.